# Microsoft Graph create share link for specific people

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, share, microsoft-graph-files, sharefile

I would like to share document by link in sharepoint from microsoft graph code. Default behaviour is that every person who has link can see this file. I want to make this link working just for specific people.

So my code look like this:

```
Permission permission = await _graphClient.Sites[_options.SiteId]
                        .Drives[driveId]
                        .Items[itemId]
                        .CreateLink("view", "organization")
                        .Request()
                        .PostAsync();
```

This create share link for all people in organization. Now I would like to grant permissions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-grant?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

```
await graphClient.Shares["{sharedDriveItem-id}"].Permission
    .Grant(roles,recipients)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

But I have no idea what should be in place "{sharedDriveItem-id}". When I put there itemId it doesn't work. Also if I put there permission.link.webUrl it also doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I found solution. There are few steps:

1. As sharedDriveItem-id I used encoded webUrl following by this instruction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
2. When I was creating link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in place scope i put "users"- there is no option like that in documentation but without that it doesn't work
3. I added Prefer in header https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
4. I was using clientSecret/clientId authorization so I had to add azure app access to Sites.Manage.All and Sites.FullControl.All in Graph Api Permissions

Everything works If you using Microsoftg.Graph nuget in newest version (4.3 right now if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Once you create the shared link the response object returns an id, that's what you should use in place of the {sharedDriveItem-id}. See a similar response object below.

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "id": "123ABC", // this is the sharedDriveItem-id
  "roles": ["write"],
  "link": {
    "type": "view",
    "scope": "anonymous",
    "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/A6913278E564460AA616C71B28AD6EB6",
    "application": {
      "id": "1234",
      "displayName": "Sample Application"
    },
  },
  "hasPassword": true
}
```

Comment: I found a solution in this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.  I had to use encoded webUrl. To create it I had to follow the instruction from documentation.  I didn't try your way so maybe there are two solutions ;)